# To find a time zone where all 8 positions in a specific time zone exist

Tags: python

```
test = {"19:00" : {
        "MT": [
            "Husky",
            "Joke Bear",
            "꾸랭"
        ],
        "ST": [
            "Husky",
            "Joke Bear",
            "꾸랭"
        ],
        "MH": [
            "히와"
        ],
        "SH": [
            "네모",
            "러나"
        ],
        "D1": [
            "스테잇",
            "네모",
            "몽구",
            "Husky"
        ],
        "D2": [
            "스테잇",
            "네모",
            "몽구",
            "Husky"
        ],
        "D3": [
            "은빈"
        ],
        "D4": [
            "네모",
            "은빈",
            "Husky"
        ]
    }}

position_list ={ #expect result
    "MT": '꾸랭',
    "ST": 'Joke Bear',
    "MH": '히와',
    "SH": '러나',
    "D1": '스테잇',
    "D2": '몽구',
    "D3": '은빈',
    "D4": '네모'
    }
```

In the time between 18:00 and 05:00,
We're conducting a survey of party members' schedules for 8 positions

Some party members can play different positions

In conclusion, I'd like to have a non-redundant number of people
I'd like to do a headcount on 8 positions

I've tried many different ways, but it's too difficult, so I'm looking for help

Comment: Your problem is equivalent to [Maximum Bipartite Matching problem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-bipartite-matching/). There should be many solutions for this problem if you Google it

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov That was a huge help!